# JQuery animate "width: toggle" causing intermittent flicker

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently working on a tool that has a tabbed section that toggles width to max and zero when a tab is clicked.  The whole div that contains the tab and the section is fixed and positioned to the top right of the window.  It's 95% there, but has an intermittent flicker that occurs when the expanded section has it's width toggled down to zero using the `$.animate({width: "toggle"});` method.  Any ideas on what might be causing it?

Here it is in a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Tgdrb.  I tried to simplify it as best I could so that it still showed the problem but wasn't totally out of context from how it would actually look on a page.  I'm also tagging this as a CSS question, as I wonder if it is the way I've structured my CSS that is causing the problem (I would not be surprised if it is).

Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you devving in Chrome? Looks like a simple Chrome redraw bug/issue - doesn't appear to happen for me in FF or IE.

Comment: I see it jump in chrome, usually getting rid of margin fixes the jumpy animation, but it doesn't seem to be helping

Comment: @Scott Selby - I also tried some other tweaks (removing the overlaps and such). To no avail. So I just put it down to another Chrome issue, or the way jQuery works in Chrome. (Also looks fine in Safari).

Comment: Awesome, I was pulling my hair out trying to understand what was the problem.  Kind of a shame that its the browser, but at least I know there is nothing I can do (besides design it differently, I suppose!)   Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is curious, there is a way to do this that is pure CSS3.  It won't work in IE (yet), but it gracefully degrades, so it works rather nicely.

Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Tgdrb/17/

So yeah, the answer to this:  Chrome causes a redraw.  If you don't like the effect, find a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: wish everyone would post a css3 to any jquery `animate` question